# SELECT rows having equal column(c1) value and adding adding another column(c2) value. Performing same for all the distinct column values for column c1

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write an SQL Query for MySQL Database which gives me the data according to the necessary conditions

I have a table having structure like this

```
id: orderId
amount : itemAmount
rate : itemRate
time : orderTime
```

Now I have to select all the rows having same rates and then have to add all the items having same rates. This should work for each rate means for eg.

> row with id 1 is having rate $20 with 2 items and row 3 is having rate $20 with 5 items
>
> row with id 2 is having rate $40 with 4 items and row 4 is having rate $40 with 7 items

I should get result is

```
rate: $20 totalItem : 7
rate: $40 totalItem : 11
```

Comment: Your table structure isn't clear at all. Are the columns called `id`, `amount`, `rate` and `time`, or `orderId`, `itemAmount`, `itemRate` and `orderTime`? What do the names on the other side of the colons mean?

Comment: What did you try? Have you looked into SUM() and GROUP BY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, I don't know what your columns are called, I'll assume in my answer they're called `id`, `amount`, `rate` and `time`.

```
SELECT rate, COUNT(*) AS totalItems -- Select the rate, and count everything
FROM theRelevantTable               -- Use the rows in this table
GROUP BY rate                       -- But do the selection per group.
```

In clearer English:

Group the rows in theRelevantTable by their `rate`, then, for every group, give me the rate and count how many rows there are in the group.

I hope this is what you meant. I do not entirely understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this? [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4cee/1) to play with

**ASSUMPTIONS:** you have a table called orders with columns rate, amount, time, id.

amount stores a quantity of items, rate is the price they are at, and time is when it occurred.

```
SELECT 
    rate, 
    SUM(amount) 
FROM orders
GROUP BY rate
```

Comment: Ah, I think I misinterpreted the question and this is what the OP wanted. I must say, the question is quite hard to read.

Comment: @11684 I completely agree.. I figured if it isn't how you said to do it then i'll post another way to do it.. we can knock them out haha.. it sounds like he stores a count already in the database which is why I went with this method :)  +1 for trying :)